# Is it ok to short two phases of a wind turbine together through a transformer?

Tags: power-electronics, generator, power-generation, windturbine

I have a wind turbine that I intend to measure the speed of by measuring the frequency between two of the phases and then relate the value to the speed of the generator.

The frequency meter couldn't pick the frequency due to which I assume to be the low voltage. I connected two phases to a step up transformer and the frequency meter now reading the frequency of the signal.

However, I am concerned about this connection as it's shorting these two phases through the transformer and I need help.
[image: diagram]

Comment: Can you please clarify what's the speed of through?

Comment: Turbine voltage will usually be adequate for speed measurement - but if a transformer is neededI guess it's not :-) :-( || Using an AC voltmeter measure phase to phase voltage with and without transfomer connected with the same turbine speed in each case.  If the voltage does not change by more thn a few prcent then the transformr does not constitute a significant load.

Comment: @Shamooooot Just an odd question: Would it be possible to just buy a mechanical mouse with a rubber ball and just place that against the shaft?

Answer (score 3):

It's neither 'shortening', nor shorting (which is what I think you mean) the two phases, as long as the transformer has a sufficient voltage rating at the frequency the turbine is operating at. If it does, then it will only draw a small magnetising current.